# check the file extension with long file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, iso

i check the extension of a file (.iso or .img):

```
set extension=%~x1
set typefile=0
FOR %%a IN (.iso .img) DO (
    if %%a==%extension% set /a typefile=!typefile!+1
)

if %typefile%==0 (
    GOTO NOMOUNT
) else (
    GOTO MOUNT
)
```

its works, but the problem is when the file have a filename like this for example:

```
9600.16384.130821-1623_x64fre_Client_IT-IT-IRM_CCSA_DV5.ISO
```

in this case the `%typefile%` is `set=0` also if the file is an iso.

Comment: @mklement0: Not the case, unfortunately. `extension` receives the er, extension as ".xyz". The `for` loop is simply matching the strings `.iso` and `.img` against that - it's a simple list, not attempting to match a [part] filename.

Comment: @mklement0: The root of the problem is OP's misdiagnosis. No crime in that - it's what keeps us in business. Had OP twigged that the problem was character-case, there would have been no need to raise the question. Hence altering the title, whilst quite logical, to me is the same as posting an answer by editing the question body, which is an invalid edit.

Comment: @Magoo with your fix the script works fine, but if i use '(*.iso *.img)' does not work, why?

Comment: @Magoo: There is too much confusion around this question, so I will remove my other comments here soon so as to avoid further confusion; thanks for the conversation, though; the answer I've since provided hopefully does a better job of clearing up the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `if %%a` to `if /i %%a` which makes the string-match case-insensitive.

BTW, `set /a typefile=!typefile!+1` could just as easily be `set /a typefile+=1`

Answer (score 0):

**Your immediate problem is NOT related to long filenames**, but to case-sensitivity when comparing strings - see @Magoo's answer.

However, overall it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve; for instance, your `for` loop enumerates *string literals* - `.iso` and `.img` - rather than trying to match *filenames in the current folder* with *patterns* `*.iso` and `*.img`.

The following solution assumes that you want to **count all files in the current folder whose filename extension case-insensitively matches the extension passed in as the 1st argument** (including the initial `.`):

```
 REM The extension to match; specify _with_ initial `.`, e.g. `.iso`
 REM `~x` ensures that if a whole filename was specified, only the extension
 REM is extracted.  
set extension=%~x1

set typefile=0
FOR %%a IN (*%extension%) DO (
    set /a typefile+=1
)

if %typefile% EQU 0 (
    GOTO NOMOUNT
) else (
    GOTO MOUNT
)
```

Note:

- Using a wildcard pattern such as `*.iso` always performs case-INsensitive matching; e.g., `*.iso` will match both files named `f1.iso` and `f2.ISO`.
- When comparing *numbers* for equality, `EQU` is better than `==`.
- Using `set /a` inside a `for` loop works even if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is NOT in effect.